# todonotes: show [inline], hide all others

Tags: todonotes

I use the following package

```
\usepackage{todonotes}
```

for my thesis.

It's working very well so far.

```
\todo[inline]{Todo #1: comments/ todos about status for professor or lecture}
\todo{Todo #2: comments for internal use. Just for me.}
```

Now I would like to set todos of category #2 as invisible temporarily.

But I don't want to touch all todos separately.

Is there any possibility with

```
\renewcommand{}[]{}
```

or something like that?

Here the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[%
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{blindtext}  %lorem ipsum
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos, ngerman]{todonotes}

\begin{document}

% list of todos
\listoftodos{}

% lorem ipsum
\blindtext
%Todo #1: comments/ todos about status for professor or lecture
\todo[inline]{Todo \#1: comments/ todos about status for professor or lecture}
% lorem ipsum
\blindtext
%Todo #2: comments for internal use. Just for me.
\todo{Todo \#2: comments for internal use. Just for me.}
% lorem ipsum
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

---

The post (in German) at golatex.de: http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,79718.html#79718

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you post a full working example? Compilable but minimal.

Comment: I added a minimum example.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the source code of the `todonotes` packages [here on Github](https://github.com/henrikmidtiby/todonotes/blob/master/todonotes.dtx). In the file `todonotes.dtx`, on line 1618, `todonotes` defines the command `\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine` which prints the non-inline note. A simple way to remove all non-inline notes is to redefine this command to do nothing:

```
% Don't print any [non-inline] notes
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine}{}
\makeatother
```

There is one problem with this approach: The ToDo note is still shown in the List of ToDo's. The command which adds items to the List of ToDo's is defined 
on lines 1649ff. To remove the non-inline notes, you can add an `\if` clause, which checks whether the current ToDo note is `[inline]` or not, and only call the command if it is inline:

```
% Remove [non-inline] notes from List of Todo's
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@addElementToListOfTodos}{%
    % New: check if note is [inline]
    \if@todonotes@inlinenote%
    % if yes: print!, if no: do nothing
    \if@todonotes@colorinlistoftodos%
    \addcontentsline{tdo}{todo}{%
        \fcolorbox{\@todonotes@currentbordercolor}%
        {\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}%
        {\textcolor{\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}{o}}%
        \ \@todonotes@caption}%
    \else%
    \addcontentsline{tdo}{todo}{\@todonotes@caption}%
    \fi%
    \else%
    \fi}%
\makeatother
```

Comment: Wow, that's great and exactly what I need. Thank you so much for your quick answer!